# What files does Déjà Dup back up?

Tags: 15.10, 16.04, deja-dup

Does Déjà Dup backup everything on my computer of just some files?
Can Déjà Dup backup everything on my computer?
Thanks guys and sorry for the noob question.

Answer (score 0):

To see the current configuration, open Deja Dup, go to "Folders to save" and "Folders to ignore".

You can also get this info from terminal using these commands:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.DejaDup include-list
gsettings get org.gnome.DejaDup exclude-list
```

I would recommend just to backup your home folder, and exclude less important folders like .cache, .dbus, and .gvfs. (I can find you more info on exclusions if needed.)

I'm not sure if it can backup the whole directory tree, but anyway there isn't any reason I can think of that a home user would need to do that. If you give more details about what you want to do, we can better answer the question.

Comment: how to exclude specific file types please?

Comment: @Gaurav Please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/861132/631039