# How to exclude specific file types in Déjà Dup backup

Tags: 16.04, backup, deja-dup

I want to take regular backups of my web development project files but would like to ignore not so important files like images, vendor files, etc. There is a way to exclude folders but how to exclude by file type?

Comment: It seems like you [can't exclude them based on the extension](https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/374274).

Comment: You might consider using `rsync` instead.

Comment: You can `save` or `ignore` only at the folder level.

Comment: @wjandrea: i don't think so, since `rsync` is just for syncing files and not for a backup! - there is a difference between these two tasks. **--** and by the way: `deja-dup` is rather a GUI-application and `rsync` has a CLI only; although there is with `grsync` a rudimentary GUI.

Comment: but `rsnapshot` is for making backups: it is based on `rsync`, folders, files and file types can be ex-/included but it has still a CLI only. but there are some GUIs based on it like `backintime`...